# After 6 months of studying German, I still struggle to speak; how do I make progress?

Tags: speaking, german

So, It has been 6 months since I started my Journey with German. It's been really fun, and I really like the language, but I am starting to feel like all this time that I have spent isn't giving me the expected ROI, I have but many MANY hours a day studying, whether it be vocab, grammar or simply reading a bit, the problem is I can't speak it, like, It will take me like 1 min to form a sentence and that would still be wrong, I watch YouTube videos from German YouTubers and can understand the context of what is being talked about...

My question is where do I go from here? I find grammar extremely boring and honestly, is stressing me out, I can't stay seated, I get angry at every mistake I make, but I realize I can remember so much and probably should practice speaking, so I can remember the patterns that way but then get worried I will forget the grammar in doing so, in short, I am stuck in a cycle! Do I watch movies in German? Do I read and then try to summarize it in my own words? What do I do? I have the Goethe B2 exam In 2,5 Months.

Comment: not for speaking practice but maybe you find it interesting - [my answer](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/a/5660/10761) for another question

Comment: "I can't stay seated" - you can try Prof Arguelles' shadowing while walking around, while working out, etc. Look him up on YouTube for demonstrations.

Comment: Danke sehr ___________

Comment: Try watching German movies and series online. Turn on the closed captions. Listen and repeat. That said, it takes years to learn a language well, not six months.

Comment: I get that, It took me years to learn English and still make mistakes here and there, I just want to pass my German Exam and that's it.